# Not getting dummy json response as Expected but Error

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

As per the following code I must get a dummy json response, but instead it is showing me an error. Why?

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

$.ajax({
  url: root + '/posts/1',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference: 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to snippet, you are missing jquery. You have to load it before you use it.

Comment: You are using Jquery. please add jquery.js script file reference in your html !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is:

> {   "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
>   "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",   "lineno": 17,   "colno":
>   1 }

So you need to add jquery as script like this:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

You can also take a look at jquery [page](http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: Type "look" instead of "loot"

Comment: @Deadpool Thanks.